# TensorFlow: "Expected axis -1 of input shape..."

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

```
import tensorflow.keras as keras
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

if __name__ == "__main__":
    file = pd.read_csv("datensatz.csv")

    file.loc[file['species'] == 'Iris-setosa', 'species'] = 0
    file.loc[file['species'] == 'Iris-versicolor', 'species'] = 1
    file.loc[file['species'] == 'Iris-virginica', 'species'] = 2

    data = file.to_numpy()

    train_x, test_x, train_y, test_y = train_test_split(data[:, :4], data[:, 4], test_size=0.20)

    encoder = OneHotEncoder(sparse=False)

    train_y = encoder.fit_transform(train_y.reshape(-1, 1))
    test_y = encoder.fit_transform(test_y.reshape(-1, 1))

    model = keras.models.Sequential([
        # sepal length, sepal width, petal length, petal width, species as number
        Dense(units=1, name="Input", input_shape=(4,), activation="relu"),
        Dense(units=4, activation='relu', name="Hidden"),
        Dense(units=3, activation='softmax', name="Output")
    ])

    model.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(), loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
    model.summary()

    model.fit(train_x.astype('float'), train_y, verbose=2, batch_size=5, epochs=100)
    print('Accuracy:', model.evaluate(test_x.astype('float'), test_y)[1])

    insert = np.array([6.1, 3.0, 4.6, 1.4]).astype('float')
    print(model.predict(x=insert))
```

Hi guys, I'm trying to predict something, but I get a really strange error(TensorFlow is really known for that!), btw. I use the famous Iris dataset.
At first, I could train the modul, that works fine, as expected.

> Epoch 100/100
> 24/24 - 0s - loss: 0.2863 - accuracy: 0.9333
> 1/1 [==============================] - 0s 999us/step - loss: 0.2402 - accuracy: 0.9333
> That's good enough! The model evaluate works as well.
> Accuracy: 0.9333333373069763

My train_x data looks like this:

```
[[5.9 3.0 4.2 1.5]
 [5.4 3.0 4.5 1.5]
 [5.6 3.0 4.5 1.5]
 [5.7 3.8 1.7 0.3]
 [5.1 3.3 1.7 0.5]
 [6.4 2.9 4.3 1.3]
 [7.7 3.8 6.7 2.2]
 [6.0 3.4 4.5 1.6]
...]
```

insert = np.array([6.1, 3.0, 4.6, 1.4]).astype('float')
print(model.predict(x=insert))

That dosen't work! I tried it with an element of the testset as well, but that gave me the same result, a really nice and bad to read error.

> ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 4 but received input with shape [None, 1]

Frankly I have no idea, what tensorflow is trying to tell me.
How can I fix it? I just want to predict, what flower could be considered.
If anyone is interessted in the dataset:
https://www.kaggle.com/akashsri99/deep-learning-iris-dataset-keras

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Predict need batch dimension. Try this:

```
insert = np.array([[6.1, 3.0, 4.6, 1.4]]).astype('float')
```

Comment: Leel, that works just fine, thank you and what the hack is a Batch Dimension? xD This double bracket?

Comment: @Simon2215 your data is 1D. Tensorflow working with mini-batches of data (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_gradient_descent).  So you have to add 1 dimension. Adding brackets convert the shape of your data from (4,) to (1, 4), where 1 is batch dimension